# Python pdfminer.six doubles or tripples each line in an lt_obj.get_text()

Tags: python, pdfminer

i experience strange behavior with pdfminer.six.
I'm trying to parse paragraphs from contract documents.
On many documents, everything works fine, but on some others, this happens:
I use lt_obj.get_text() to extract the text of a paragraph and get each line doubled or tripled.

Example (anonymized):
[PDF Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1JoC.png)

And what i get from print(lt_obj.get_text()) is:

```
"Line1 Content
Line1 Content
Line2 Content
Line2 Content
Line3 Content
Line3 Content
Line4 Content
Line4 Content
Line5 Content
Line5 Content"
```

I thought it had something to do with recursively getting the lt_objects that contain text, but as you see in my code, i turned that off and still get these results.
However, this does not happen in all my documents, only sometimes. But if it happens, it happens for the whole document and all its paragraphs.

My code:

```
def parse_layout(layout, page_counter, doc):
        for lt_obj in layout:
        if isinstance(lt_obj, LTTextBox) or isinstance(lt_obj, LTTextLine):
            text = lt_obj.get_text()
            print(text)
        elif isinstance(lt_obj, LTFigure):
            pass
            #parse_layout(lt_obj, page_counter, doc)  # Recursive
```